# regex for large currency amounts

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to write an expression that extracts numbers from a string with corresponding currency signs and potential amount abbreviations (m or k):

```
text <- "$10000 and $10,000 and $5m and $50m and $50.2m and $50,2m"
str_extract(text, "\\$(\\d+)[a-z]+") # solution_1
str_extract(text, "\\$(\\d+)+") #solution_2
```

Desired output:

```
"$10000 $10,000 $5m $50m $50.2m $50,2m"
```

The problem is that `solution_1` extracts only "$5m" and `solution_2` only "$10000".

**UPDATE**: @Tim Biegeleisen provided a great solution. I am also trying to get rid of a period in the end, e.g. `$50m. and...` to get `$50m`.

```
text <- "$5, $10,000, and $5m, and $50m. and $50.2m and $50,2m"
m <- gregexpr("\\$[0-9.,]+?[mbt]?(?=(?:, | |$))", text, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(text, m)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `grepexpr` with `regmatches`:

```
text <- "$10000 and $10,000 and $5m and $50m and $50.2m and $50,2m"
m <- gregexpr("\\$[0-9.,]+[mbt]?", text)

regmatches(text, m)
[[1]]
[1] "$10000"  "$10,000" "$5m"     "$50m"    "$50.2m"  "$50,2m"
```

### Demo

I am assuming that only numbers, comma, and decimal point, would compose a given amount string.  I also assume that the amount might end in `m`, `b`, or `t` (for million, billion, trillion).

Comment: Works perfectly and thank you for the explanation! Any way to include the pound sign, so it matches both $100 and £100 etc.?

Comment: @Misha Yeah, just use something like `[$£][0-9.,]+[mbt]?`.

Comment: Follow-up: is there a way to exclude a comma and period after the number if there are no more numbers after, i.e. `$1.2k, etc`, so it returns `$1.2k` and not `$1.2k,`

Comment: @Misha I have [setup a demo](http://rextester.com/IJTLJQ23195) which appears to resolve your issue.  If you have other requirements I would recommend opening a new question.  When you keep changing requirements you invalidate all the work which has already been done by other people.

Comment: Thank you! Will start a new question to get rid of the period in the end: e.g., `$50m. etc`.

Answer (score 0):

Could also do it e.g. this way

```
txt = unlist(strsplit(text, split = " "))
txt[grep("\\$\\d+((,|\\.)?)(\\d*)?(m)?", txt)]

[1] "$10000"  "$10,000" "$5m"     "$50m"    "$50.2m"  "$50,2m"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be we could use `gsub` as the OP's expected output showed as a single string

```
gsub("\\b[A-Za-z]+,?|[,.](\\s)", "\\1", text)
#[1] "$10000  $10,000  $5m  $50m  $50.2m  $50,2m"
#[2] "$5 $10,000  $5m  $50m  $50.2m  $50,2m"
```

#### data

```
text <- c( "$10000 and $10,000 and $5m and $50m and $50.2m and $50,2m",
      "$5, $10,000, and $5m, and $50m. and $50.2m and $50,2m")
```