# regex to exclude a period after a number

Tags: r, regex

I have a problem getting rid of a period in `$50m.` This is a follow-up question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587609/regex-for-large-currency-amounts). The original questions was answered by @Tim Biegeleisen.

```
text <- "$5, $10,000, and $5m, and $50m. and $50.2m and $50,2m"
m <- gregexpr("\\$[0-9.,]+?[mbt]?(?=(?:, | |$))", text, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(text, m)
```

Desired output: 
`"$5" "$10,000" "$5m" "$50m" "$50.2m"  "$50,2m"`

Comment: Seems to work fine without fancy lookahead stuff: `m <- gregexpr("\\$[.,0-9]*[0-9][mbt]?", text); regmatches(text, m)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the regex to

```
\\$[0-9.,]+?[mbt]?(?=(?:[.,] | |$))
                        ^^^^
```

in order to get rid of the dot.

Comment: this matches invalid values like `$. and $, and $000001 and $3.`
`$3,` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xKG0GI/2)

Comment: @Matt.G so does op's regex. The question is about the dot, not matching "valid" currency values

Answer (score 1):

Try regex: `\$[1-9]\d*(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?[mbt]?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xKG0GI/1)

Comment: Thanks for the demo, never realized such a website existed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already in your old question which was answered by erocoar.  Although, he created an array.

```
text <- "$5, $10,000, and $5m, and $50m. and $50.2m and $50,2m"
m <- gregexpr("\\$\\d+((,|\\.)?)(\\d*)?(m)?", text, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(text, m)
```